# Palindrome Fail

Tags: java, palindrome, comparison-operators

Hello (my first post), 
I should write a program that checks if a sentence or a word  is a Palindrome. For this I must use Stacks.
The thing is that I print both solutions out in the console but even if they are the same it returns false.

My Code:

```
public class Palindrome {
  // Test if text is a palindrome.
  // Ignore upper/lower case, white space, and punctuation.
  //
  public static boolean isPalindrome(String text) {
    boolean ispalin =false;
    char tmp;
    String temp = text;
    String text2 = "";
    String check = "";
    Stack<Character> stacktext = new Stack<Character>();
    Stack<Character> stackcheck = new Stack<Character>();
    text = text.toLowerCase();



    for (int j = 0; j < text.length(); j++) {
      if(     text.charAt(j) != ' '&&
              text.charAt(j) != ','&&
              text.charAt(j) != '?'&&
              text.charAt(j) != '.'&&   //delete some symbols
              text.charAt(j) != '!'&&
              text.charAt(j) != '-'){


        tmp = text.charAt(j);
        text2 += tmp;
      }
    }



    for (int j = text.length()-1; j > -1; j--) {
      if(     text.charAt(j) != ' '&&
              text.charAt(j) != ','&&
              text.charAt(j) != '?'&&
              text.charAt(j) != '.'&&
              text.charAt(j) != '!'&&
              text.charAt(j) != '-'){


        tmp = text.charAt(j);
        check += tmp;
      }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < text2.length(); i++) {
      stacktext.push(text2.charAt(i));
    }
    for (int i = check.length()-1; i != -1; i--) {
      stackcheck.push(check.charAt(i));
    }
    System.out.println(stackcheck);
    System.out.println(stacktext);
    if (stackcheck == stacktext) return true;
    else return false;
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(isPalindrome("Na, Fakir, Paprika-Fan?"));
  }
}
```

The Output:

```
[n, a, f, a, k, i, r, p, a, p, r, i, k, a, f, a, n]
[n, a, f, a, k, i, r, p, a, p, r, i, k, a, f, a, n]
false
```

Comment: @Gereon Where is the OP comparing strings (they are - incorrectly - using `==` on a `Stack`, this may be the same underlying reason, but nonetheless, this question is not really suitable)

Comment: Why not just use Character.isLetter(char)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is that your comparison

```
//...
if (stackcheck == stacktext) return true;
    else return false;
//...
```

will always evaluate to false, these are two different objects.

You need:

```
//...
if (stackcheck.equals(stacktext)) return true;
    else return false;
//
```

Or better yet:

```
//...
return stackcheck.equals(stacktext);
//...
```

The other problem is that the strings are placed in the `Stack` in the same order and not being reversed, therefore the comparison will always evaluate to `true` no matter if the strings are paindromes or not.

[**Working sample**](https://onlinegdb.com/rJSev5xYU), using [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) to reverse the second  string `check` before adding it to `stackcheck`, of course you can do it yourself, adding it to the `Stack` in reverse order.

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String text)
{
    text = text.toLowerCase();

    String text2 = text.replaceAll("[,. !?-]", ""); //replaceAll to remove characters
    String check = new StringBuilder(text2).reverse().toString(); //reverse string

    Stack<Character> stacktext = new Stack<>();
    Stack<Character> stackcheck = new Stack<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < text2.length(); i++)
    {
        stacktext.add(text2.charAt(i));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < check.length(); i++)
    {
        stackcheck.add(check.charAt(i));
    }

    System.out.println(stackcheck);
    System.out.println(stacktext);

    return stackcheck.equals(stacktext);
}
```

Comment: i tested this but this didn't work either

Comment: i know now where the Problem was my Prof did create his own stack without an equal method but in the java doc stack there is an equal method. I used the Stack from my Prof. Thanks for the help

Comment: @Detalafol, I added a simple implementaton where you can see the differences between `equals` and `==` methods https://onlinegdb.com/rkWivdeFL

Comment: @Detalafol, so I guess the problem is that the strings are not reversed, so when you compare them they are allways equal.

Comment: @Detalafol, I added a solution to my answer, hope it helps.